# Change numbering level for one chapter only

Tags: sectioning, numbering, amsmath, chapters, sections-paragraphs

Apologies if this is duplicate but couldn't find it.

I have a document using amsmath for chapter, section & subsection numbering, & everything (theorems, lemmas etc) uses the same numbering system.

I have one chapter that has no sections or subsections (this does make sense, honest, its a 5-6 page theorem that doesn't fit with anything else).  The problem is the numbering here starts at 4.0.13 (because I haven't reset the subsection counter, presumably).

I have two options - either set it to 4.1.1 or even better, have only two part numbering in this chapter so that the theorems/lemmas can be numbered 4.1, 4.2 etc etc.  I have read quite a few posts about \numberwithin & \counterwithin but am pretty confused.

Example below - here the thm in chapter 2 is number 2.0.3 but I want it to be 2.1.1 or preferably just 2.1.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\makeatletter\@addtoreset{case}{thm}\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
 \thm@preskip=\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{case}{lem}\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
\thm@preskip=\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{chapter}{chap title}
\begin{section}{title blah}
\begin{thm}
hello
\end{thm}
\begin{subsection}{title blahh}
\begin{lem} 
hi
\end{lem}
\end{subsection}
\end{section}
\end{chapter}

\begin{chapter}{chap title 2}
\begin{thm}
hello again
\end{thm}
\end{chapter}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: In the MWE, you might just include chapter and section commands. We have to be able to reproduce the problem in order to understand and fix it. My main question is, why is a new chapter not resetting the subsection counter?

Comment: Included most of preamble incase something else is messing it up.

Comment: @ZoeKelly: The 2.0.3 stems from not having a section in the 2nd chapter, therefore subsection counter is not reset at all. Your `thm` environment resets only with `sections`, so it is frozen to `3` in that example.

Comment: Yes - I am trying to have a chapter with only one section so it seems silly to create a section as it doesn't need a title & I don't want to number it.  Sorry if I'm not being clear in what I'm attempting to do..

Answer (score 6):

There are no `chapter`, `section` or `subsection` environments. Don't use `\begin{chapter}` and similar constructions, even if they appear to work.

You can make the decision about the numbering automatic: if the section counter is zero, as it is after `\chapter`, the theorems will be numbered “chapter.theorem”, otherwise “chapter.section.theorem”. No manual resetting is needed for chapters where theorems are inside sections.

I removed the setting to `\thm@space@setup` because I don't really understand what they're supposed to do.

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}

\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]

\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}[thm]

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{thm}{chapter}
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\thethm}{%
  \ifnum\value{section}=0
    \thechapter.%
  \else
    \thesection.%
  \fi
  \arabic{thm}%
}
\renewcommand{\thecase}{\arabic{case}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{chap title}
\section{title blah}
\begin{thm}
hello
\end{thm}

\subsection{title blahh}
\begin{lem} 
hi
\end{lem}

\chapter{chap title 2}
\begin{thm}
hello again
\end{thm}

\end{document}
```

Note how it's easier to reset the `case` number with every theorem.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use the `chngcntr` package and a manual reset before the 2nd chapter, via `\setcounter{thm}{0}`.

There might be some resetting afterwards necessary!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{chngcntr}%

\theoremstyle{plain}% default
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\newtheorem{conj}{Conjecture}[section]
\newtheorem{exmp}{Example}[section]
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem*{rem}{Remark}
\newtheorem*{note}{Note}
\newtheorem{case}{Case}
\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{case}{thm}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
 \thm@preskip=\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother

\makeatletter\@addtoreset{case}{lem}\makeatother
\makeatletter
\def\thm@space@setup{%
\thm@preskip=\parskip \thm@postskip=0pt}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{chapter}{chap title}
\begin{section}{title blah}
\begin{thm}
hello
\end{thm}
\begin{subsection}{title blahh}
\begin{lem} 
hi
\end{lem}
\end{subsection}
\end{section}
\end{chapter}


%%%% My addition:
\setcounter{thm}{0}
\begin{chapter}{chap title 2}
%%%% My addition:

\counterwithin{thm}{chapter}
\begin{thm}
hello again
\end{thm}
\end{chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Brilliant, thank you (didn't affect next chapter numbering either).

Comment: @ZoeKelly: That's due to your usage of `\begin{chapter}` perhaps. As egreg stated in his solution, one should not use `\begin{chapter}` etc. but `\chapter` etc.